# Logging into Windows Live from Zune Desktop vs. web

Tags: firewall, zune

In my company, IT has blocked the use of Windows Live Messenger client, but I am able to log in to Web Messenger just fine.

When I try to sign in to the same Live ID via Zune Desktop software (latest version, with all patches applied) on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, it fails with a generic error code C00D11CD. The "web help" page is [here](http://www.zune.net/en-US/support/webhelp/C00D11CD.htm?&webhelp_mpver=4.8.2098.0&webhelp_id=C00D11CD&webhelp_contextid=1&webhelp_originalid=80048862&webhelp_locale=en-US) and provides no real help nor resolution.

I suspect Zune Desktop mimics WLM then and since that protocol/port is blocked, I cannot sign in from the desktop software? Anything else I can check/fix to successfully log in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your company has blocked access to the servers that Windows Live Messenger and Zune software communicate with to sign in. I don't think there is a solution.

You can always try signing in on `zune.net`.

You can also try installing [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com), enable HTTPS tracing and then use this to see what service API call is failing. This should give you some clue on whether connections are being blocked.